# Facebook vanity URL causing issues in like box

Tags: facebook-likebox

I regularly create Facebook like boxs and insert them onto sites via the I frame method. It's always worked with no issue.

Recently I had to try https://Facebook.com/plumber.blackpool

But it failed to preview the box on facebooks like box code generator. Its iframe code won't work either.

My assumption is because it's vanity URL has a period . within it.

What can I do to work around? How can I find what the pages original long URL was?

Answer (score 0):

instead of the fb vanity url, find out the page ID value, and use it.

also, page privacy settings can have an impact -- if the post are not "all public", then the timeline will not show to ppl who are not logged into fb, while on your 3rd party website.

or it is something about the under/over 13yo content settings.